# Phonegap developer app is not supported in HTC 628

Tags: cordova

Phonegap developer app is not supported in HTC 628. What should I do to test my app on real device

Comment: which android version is installed on our device?

Comment: you need to install adb driver in your system for debug and run app in your device. or you can manually take copy of .apk from platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk after cordova build android and paste in your device and install from there